# Inner join in regular mysql tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

In `mysql` I've got a table called `users` which contains the list of users in the system...

```
id | name | surname | active
____________________________

1    John   Doe       True
2    Steve  Smith     True
...
```

and then there's another table `cars` which holds the cars each user has bought:

```
 id | model | brand | cc    | user_id
 ____________________________________

 1    330     BMW     2000    2
 2    Golf    VW      1600    1
 ...
```

What I need to do is write an sql statement that does the following:

```
for each of the users who have bought a car, 
show a list of them along with the number of cars they've purchased
```

For instance:
User Steve Smith has a total of 1 car.
User John Doe has a total of 1 car. (or whatever the number).

I think I have to do some sort of inner join but I am not entirely sure on how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner join will deliver that. For users with no cars, they would not appear. Note the use of column aliases on id to differentiate columns with a join that have same column name in both tables (`id`).

Note that Sally Higgins does not appear, as `inner join` (a.k.a. `join`) fetches matches. A `left join` would be used to pick up Sally with her lack of car detail in addition to the others.

### Schema

```
create table users
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    firstName varchar(100) not null,
    lastName varchar(100) not null,
    active int not null
);
insert users(firstName,lastName,active) values ('John','Doe',1),('Steve','Smith',1),('Sally','Higgins',1);

create table cars
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    model varchar(100) not null,
    brand varchar(100) not null,
    cc int not null,
    user_id int not null -- don't forget a foreign key constraint here
);
insert cars(model,brand,cc,user_id) values ('330','BMW',2000,2),('Golf','VW',1600,1),('Pinto','Ford',1000,1);
```

### Query

```
select u.id,u.firstName,u.lastName,u.active,c.id as carId,c.model,c.brand,c.cc 
from users u 
join cars c 
on c.user_id=u.id;
+----+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| id | firstName | lastName | active | carId | model | brand | cc   |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  1 | John      | Doe      |      1 |     2 | Golf  | VW    | 1600 |
|  1 | John      | Doe      |      1 |     3 | Pinto | Ford  | 1000 |
|  2 | Steve     | Smith    |      1 |     1 | 330   | BMW   | 2000 |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

### Left Join to pick up Sally (car-less Sally)

```
select u.id,u.firstName,u.lastName,u.active,c.id as carId,c.model,c.brand,c.cc 
from users u 
left join cars c 
on c.user_id=u.id;
+----+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| id | firstName | lastName | active | carId | model | brand | cc   |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  2 | Steve     | Smith    |      1 |     1 | 330   | BMW   | 2000 |
|  1 | John      | Doe      |      1 |     2 | Golf  | VW    | 1600 |
|  1 | John      | Doe      |      1 |     3 | Pinto | Ford  | 1000 |
|  3 | Sally     | Higgins  |      1 |  NULL | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```